# Searching for records with MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to search a database for terms typed in by a user. This is the MYSQL statement I am using:

```
SELECT CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, City, Rep, id 
FROM calls 
WHERE Rep='JSC' && CompanyName || FirstName || LastName || PhoneMisc1 || Email || City LIKE '%$terms%'
```

The problem is, it does not only return records where Rep='JSC' but the rest of it works in returning the columns that are like the terms.

Comment: _it does not only return records where Rep='JSC' but the rest of it works in returning the columns that are like the terms._ - you sure about that?  Yes `||` is okay for `OR` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

Comment: || and OR are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
SELECT CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, City, Rep, id  
FROM calls WHERE Rep='JSC' and 
(
CompanyName LIKE '%$terms%' 
or
FirstName LIKE '%$terms%' 
 or 
 LastName LIKE '%$terms%' 
or 
PhoneMisc1 LIKE '%$terms%' 
or 
Email LIKE '%$terms%' 
or 
City LIKE '%$terms%'
)
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted; care to explain the reason behind downvote?